# 404 Not Found Error on every page other than index.html

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, html

I have my Apache server all setup with a domain pointing to its IP address. When I go to the domain it serves me the "It Works!" page. I have another page in the    `/var/www/html` directory called `page.html`. However, when I type in `www.mydomain.com/page.html` is gives me a *404 Not Found* error. And when I type `www.mydomain.com/index.html`, it brings me right to the index page which is the "it works!" one. I have no idea whats going on and I've been scouring the internet in search of an answer and I have come back empty-handed. My domain provider is Ipage if that is any help.

[image: 404 Not Found Page screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the contents of the conversation taking place here have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49398/discussion-on-question-by-dave-404-not-found-error-on-every-page-other-than-inde).

Comment: Is the `index.html` page present in the same directory as your `page.html`? Could you check they both have correct permissions (`ls -l`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling mod_rewrite with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

You can also try checking any config files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and ensuring that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` and *not* `none`.

After either or both is done, restart Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Can you explain how this could help, especially without any rewrite rules?

Comment: @Melebius without mod_rewrite or allowing overrides your server may not be able to correctly serve files due to (most likely) not recognizing the connection between domain name and folder location.